# perform arithmetic operations with multiple variables that contain floating point in bash

Tags: bash, floating-point

I'm writing a script in bash and i need to add a third variable to this code: `Res=$(echo $VAR1-$VAR2|bc)` or this code: `Res=$(bc <<< "$VAR1-$VAR2")` (both allow me to calculate decimal numbers) , i need to do the following calculation:  `Res=$VAR3-($VAR1-$VAR2)`

Comment: i can't do that `Res=$(echo $VAR3-($VAR1-$VAR2)|bc)` so what is the right syntax?

Comment: See Tom's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like you just need to do this:

```
Res=$(bc <<< "$VAR3-($VAR1-$VAR2)")
```

The three variables are expanded in the shell and passed to `bc`, which performs the calculation. This is no different to your examples with two variables.

The double quotes around the whole command are important, as they prevent the `(` and `)` from being interpreted by the shell. Your example with two variables works because the string only contains "safe" characters like numbers and `-` (no spaces or other characters that are significant to the shell).

In general, you should always quote your strings with single quotes for literals and double quotes when they contain variables.

You can pass the string using `echo` if you want:

```
Res=$(echo "$VAR3-($VAR1-$VAR2)" | bc)
```

Using `<<<` is better because it doesn't use a pipe, so doesn't create any subshells. Again, the double quotes are needed here.